# How to mock a function call in the method I am testing - currently using NSubsitute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I am new to trying to mock things in unit tests...

Example Code simplified for posting:

```
namespace MockInvestigate.Monitor
{
    internal interface IAgentRepo
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> GetAgentAppSettings(string moduleName);
    }

    public class AgentRepo : IAgentRepo
    {
        public virtual Dictionary<string, string> GetAgentAppSettings(string moduleName)
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, string> { { "real", "data" } };
        }
    }
}
```

This is the method I want to unit test - but override the call to GetAgentAppSettings

```
namespace MockInvestigate
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static bool IsInitialized(string taskName)
        {
            AgentRepo ar = new AgentRepo();
            var arReturn = ar.GetAgentAppSettings(taskName);

            return arReturn.ContainsKey("real");
        }
    }
}
```

The unit test - trying to mock the call to 'GetAgentAppSettings'

```
[TestMethod]

public void TestMethod1()
{
 var repo = Substitute.ForPartsOf<AgentRepo>();
 var appReturn = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "bogus", "bogus2" } };
 repo.GetAgentAppSettings("somevalue").ReturnsForAnyArgs(appReturn);

 bool retValue = Class1.IsInitialized("somevalue");

 Assert.IsFalse(retValue);
}
```

When my test is run, the real `GetAgentAppSettings` is called, returning "real", "data" and not the bogus data I want. 
I have tried `.When(...).DoNotCallBase()`.

Can my test be modified to work? Does the underlying code need to change to work?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code under test needs to execute using your substitute instance.  This is usually achieved by constructor or property injection, or by passing the substitute directly into the method you are testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the substitute `repo`, you have to inject it inside `Class1`.
In your code, however, you are creating the `AgentRepo` inside the `IsInitialized` method, thus it's not using the substitute you created in the test method.

You have to inject the substitute by constructor injection, property injection or method injection.

As the name suggests, constructor injection is when you inject the dependency from the constructor. Since the method `IsInitialized` is static, that's not an option.

Likewise, property injection uses properties to inject the dependencies. You could create a static property, usually you'd stay away from it though.
It'd always use the same instance for every thread, hence you'd have to guarantee that the `AgentRepo` is thread-safe.

As last resort, you can use the method injection. You'd get the `AgentRepo` instance as a method argument and let the caller be responsible for creating it.

Since this is a small repro, I can't tell you what's the best way to deal with it. What I do know is that the `AgentRepo` must be injected into `Class1` somehow.